# Laravel Clone /Multi Collection to Model Insert

Tags: laravel

I am trying to clone a collection of existing records and create a new model for each with changing properties such as name,promotion_id etc.

```
$source_voice_messages =  VoiceMessage::wherePromotionId($promotion_id)->get();

        foreach($source_voice_messages as $source_voice_message ){

            VoiceMessage::insert($source_voice_message->toArray());
        }
```

the expected  behavior should be a new record with a new primary id.

I am getting:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1062 Duplicate entry '83' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

In addition how would I change $source_voice_message->name

Comment: Well where is new Model. Both the models are same.

Comment: And when you are picking same model data and Inserting it in the same model, then it will be a definite duplicate value

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with replicate()

```
$voice_message = VoiceMessage::find($source_voice_message->id);

            $cloned_voice_message = $voice_message->replicate();
            $cloned_voice_message->save();
```